# Switching between nvidia and nouveau drivers using gentoo-orientated guide on Debian 10

Tags: debian, systemd, drivers, gentoo, init-script

I'm using Debian 10 XFCE with nvidia driver installed from `buster-backports/non-free` repository.

I want to switch between open source nouveau and proprietary nvidia drivers on boot. I've found [a page on gentoo wiki](https://wiki.gentoo.org/wiki/Nouveau_&_nvidia-drivers_switching#Switching_using_a_single_kernel_and_systemd) describing how to do this (using systemd, grub entries and OpenGL+OpenCL implementations switching boot scripts).

But Debian and Gentoo aren't the same systems. Debian doesn't have some Gentoo's directories and files (`/etc/local.d/`, `/etc/X11/xorg.conf.d/`, `/etc/X11/xorg.conf.d/01-nv.conf`). Also I don't know how to "ensure that Mesa has been built with the `opencl` USE flag enabled" in Debian. And maybe I am missing some more important differences between these two systems also preventing me from using this guide on Debian.

What can I change in the guide to make it work on Debian?